# Windows 10 File Explorer Navigation Pane Toggle Disabled

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

My folder options are set to open Windows Explorer to the This PC page. But whenever I first open explorer, I cannot toggle the visibility of the navigation pane.

[Image: file explorer with navigation pane disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urivt.png)

If I navigate to a different folder and then back to This PC, the navigation pane is enabled again. How can I toggle the navigation pane without having to change directories first?

Comment: Try closing all Explorer windows and use `regedit` to navigate to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\NavPane`. Export the key for safe keeping, then delete the value named `ExpandedState`.

Comment: I don't know if you've undertaken a repair install yet,  but I would have tried deleting several other registry keys relating to folder views before a repair install! If that view was your only issue, a repair install was over-kill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may well be repaired with DISM and SFC.

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Try the above. If that does not work a Repair Install may be necessary.

Also make a new, test Windows User Account and Profile. Log into the new Account and test the overall operation of Navigation in the new account.

If needed, steps for a Repair Install are here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Comment: About how long should I expect for each of these steps to finish?

Comment: Total on a decent machine about 30 minutes.  Just an average but that should do it.

Comment: Even after running as admin, I get a access denied from step 2.

Comment: (a) do not forget the step to try a different User Account . However, the Access Denied error suggests the need for a Repair Install.  (b) I listed the Repair Install steps in my answer. Check al the steps because there are 3 possible methods to them.

Comment: On a different account, the problem does not occur and the navigation pane behaves normally. The repair install may work even if it may take a while. Also, the link only provides options to update or create installation media. If possible, I'll start using a different account, otherwise I will look into repair install.

Comment: If it is only the account causing the issue, you may not need the Repair. Back up the documents and email in your profile. Make very it is all backed up. Make a temporary Administrators Account. Log in, delete the bad profile and its associated user name. Restart, make the same user name and profile.  Then restore your documents and email.

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't have navigate to another folder,
2. highlight a folder under "this pc"...
3. "quick access
   toolbar"> "navigation pane" is available to click on/off